# Using !Send object on async function works, but does not work on trait function

Tags: asynchronous, rust

Suppose we have a type that is not Send.

```rust
struct NotSend {
    field: std::rc::Rc<i32>
}
```

Then, following async function can still take NotSend as its parameter and compiles well:

```rust
async fn func(not_send: NotSend) -> i32 {
    0
}
```

But when I define the same function inside of the trait, then anything that implements it does not compile.

```rust
#[async_trait]
trait A {
    async fn func(not_send: NotSend) -> i32;
}

struct S {
    
}

#[async_trait]
impl A for S {
    async fn func(not_send: NotSend) -> i32 {
        0
    }
}
```

This fails with the following message:

```
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:23:46
   |
23 |       async fn func( not_send: NotSend) -> i32 {
   |  ______________________________________________^
24 | |         0
25 | |     }
   | |_____^ future created by async block is not `Send`
   |
   = help: within `impl Future<Output = i32>`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `Rc<i32>`
note: captured value is not `Send`
  --> src/main.rs:23:20
   |
23 |     async fn func( not_send: NotSend) -> i32 {
   |                    ^^^^^^^^ has type `NotSend` which is not `Send`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn Future<Output = i32> + Send`
```

What's so different from the naive function and the function in the trait? Why one does works but not the other? [Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=72b180d28fd410987e5ba39316007432)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `async_trait` expands to something like `Pin<Box<dyn Future>>`. If we want the resulting future to be `Send`, it needs to be `Pin<Box<dyn Future + Send>>`. But this *forces* it to be `Send`, i.e. will error on non-`Send` futures. The `async_trait` crate does not have a way to know whether the future is `Send` (because the implementation of the trait is different from its declaration, and we need to decide at declaration site whether the future will be `Send` or not), so it opts to use user-defined annotations.

By default, the generated type is `Send` since most futures needs to be `Send`. However, [as explained in the documentation](https://docs.rs/async-trait/latest/async_trait/#non-threadsafe-futures), you can use `#[async_trait(?Send)]` to opt this out:

```rust
#[async_trait(?Send)]
trait A {
    async fn func(not_send: NotSend) -> i32;
}

struct S {
    
}

#[async_trait(?Send)]
impl A for S {
    async fn func(not_send: NotSend) -> i32 {
        0
    }
}
```

Comment: Very minor correction, the return type generated by the macro is `Pin<Box<dyn Future + Send>>` (the `Send` bound is applied to the inner trait object, not the `Pin`).